# Post to Spring MVC controller with domain class that has Mongo @DBref not working

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-mvc, spring-mongo

I have a domain model created for `productCategory`, and one of the fields has `@DBRef` annotated `parentCategory`, like following:

```
@Document
public class ProductCategory{
 @Id
 private String id;
 private String name;
 @DBRef
 private ProductCategory parentCategory;

 setter.getter...
}
```

My controller is simply

```
@RequestMapping(value="/api/category", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody ProductCategory addCategory(@RequestBody ProductCategory category) {
        return category;
    }
```

I tried `$ref` noted from MongoDB documentation, but I can't construct my JSON post in a way that the server recognizes the `parentCategory`. It would always give me error message like

> `org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException`: Could not read JSON: Unrecognized field "`$ref`"

I read through the http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-mongodb/docs/1.5.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#mapping-usage-references
and spring documentation and can't find anything related.

Do I need to create a custom `HTTPMessageConverter`?